# 32-bit version of VS Code for Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to get a version of VS Code that will run on 32-bit Windows 7.

[This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_can-i-run-vs-code-on-windows-7) points to the [release notes for 1.70](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70) which has a 64-bit download.

[This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_32bit-versions) provides a link to download the Insiders version, for use with 32-bit. But that version doesn't support Windows 7.

Where can I find such a version of VS Code?

Comment: Windows 7 is out of support and vscode has subsequently dropped support for that OS. You'd need to download a really old version and you'd find most extensions won't work on that anymore.

Comment: @jessehouwing I'm aware. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Looks like you might be able to leverage vscodium: https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/releases

Comment: @jessehouwing I went with VSCodium. Do you think it should be a separate answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vscodium project still releases builds for many officially unsupported platforms formerly or never supported by vscode.

You can grab a release from here:

- https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/releases

Answer (score 5):

Here:

- [System installer](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32/stable)
- [User installer](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32-user/stable)

Taken from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_previous-release-versions).

Though for some reason these don't work on my computer (Code.exe starts by dies after a bit). Who knows why...

Then there's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDu1RT6bNSA) downloading 1.50 and comments saying thank you, so I guess it worked (I didn't try because...) - very old version though. Not sure why 1.70 doesn't work on me, but anyway, according to Microsoft, it's the last one working on Windows 7, and here are the 2 links for its 32-bit Windows version. Hopefully it works for you and anyone else. This is a 2006 Pentium M DDR RAM PC anyway.

**EDIT:** I did get to try now, 9 months later xD. [1.55.2](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.55.2/win32-user/stable) is the last one that works on my computer, in case anyone finds it useful. [1.56.0](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.56.0/win32-user/stable) breaks it here.

Also, there is a ZIP somewhere for 1.70.3, but I only found the 64-bit version. **EDIT:** take a look at Alex Koster's answer - the 32-bit version of the ZIP is there.

Answer (score 2):

### VSCodium

Building on the other responses to this question above, to be able to use some of the latest features VSCodium might be your best option, unless you need Microsoft Account-enabled features.  As of April 19, 2023 I was able to run the latest release of VSCodium  1.77.3.23102 32-bit build from the ZIP archive on 64-bit Windows 7 SP1.  Note, I did not test on 32-bit Windows 7 but I imagine the 32-bit builds should run as well. Note there are messages indicating that VSCodium will soon stop receiving updates for Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2.  The funny thing is that upon clicking on the Learn More hyperlink or button you are directed to a URL from the VS Code documentation indicating versions greater than 1.70 will not run on Windows 7.

### Visual Studio Code

If you are looking specifically for VS Code, I was able to find the other 32-bit (and 64-bit) build links from the VS Code Documentation FAQ page under heading "Previous Release Versions" which I found from a StackOverflow question (# 49346733) titled "How to downgrade vscode": (Not linking to these relatively easy to find FAQ and SO question pages as I don't have enough reputation to post more than 8 links at this time and would prefer to provide direct links to the builds for download)

**32-bit builds:**

ZIP: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32-archive/stable

System Installer: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32/stable

User Installer: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32-user/stable

**64-bit builds:**

ZIP: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32-x64-archive/stable

System Installer: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32-x64/stable

User Installer: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32-x64-user/stable

With regard to the final VS Code update for Windows 7, version 1.70.3 for the ZIP archive builds, I was able to find direct links to the latest version 1.70.3 by clicking on the Gear icon in the lower left and using the built-in Download Updates option which directed me to the following URLs for the 32-bit and 64-bit editions:

**32-bit VS Code 1.70.3 ZIP archive:**

https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230/VSCode-win32-ia32-1.70.3.zip

**64-bit VS Code 1.70.3 ZIP archive:**

https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230/VSCode-win32-x64-1.70.3.zip

Unfortunately, I could not find a direct URL to download the system or user installers for version 1.70.3, although the built-in updater (accessed from the Gear icon menu in the lower left) seemed to download an updater package, creating a new directory vscode-update-[system/user]-[ia32/x64] underneath C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\ under which an .EXE file and sometimes a .flag file were written.  For the system installer versions I received a UAC prompt and was able to track down the directory and file locations from there.  (Though there was no UAC prompt for the user installer versions, I did find similar directories adjacent to the system directories under AppData\Local\Temp which I am assuming are the updaters for those versions).  Here are the SHA-256 hashes of those files, their file sizes and locations:

**32-bit system installer updater to 1.70.3:**

Sub-directory of AppData\Local\Temp: vscode-update-system-ia32\

File name: CodeSetup-stable-a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230.exe

SHA-256 Hash:
0c64ea2647a54b7cdc4d3a3c91fbcebbe43b250417c75c0437fca252572a692d

Size: 79,271,448 bytes

**64-bit system installer updater to 1.70.3:**

Sub-directory of AppData\Local\Temp: vscode-update-system-x64\

File 1 name: CodeSetup-stable-a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230.exe

SHA-256 Hash of file 1: 63a0e5beb949cbf70a8e8e78a8f2d0d8be48e6f59966769789f236fb7643711c

Size of file 1: 82,838,336 bytes

File 2 name: CodeSetup-stable-a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230.flag

SHA-256 Hash of file 2: 807d0fbcae7c4b20518d4d85664f6820aafdf936104122c5073e7744c46c4b87

Size of file 2: 4 bytes

**32-bit user installer updater to 1.70.3:**

Sub-directory of AppData\Local\Temp: vscode-update-user-ia32\

File name: CodeSetup-stable-a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230.exe

SHA-256 Hash: 1d136adc8d36a7785bd2379b643c003caeace78a3c122910ec83ec76c76cfce5

Size: 79,271,592 bytes

**64-bit user installer updater to 1.70.3:**

Sub-directory of AppData\Local\Temp: vscode-update-user-x64\

File name: CodeSetup-stable-a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230.exe

SHA-256 Hash:  b1332b48970ade9aaf4f0948fee417cabd0207aca44985798f4f941afefa32f3

Size: 82,838,544 bytes